# osx - What's the best way to "pause" a 3rd-party macOS app during launch in Swift?

Tags: macos

I've been playing around with `NSRunningApplication` in Swift 3, and I've come up with a few questions.

1. What's the best way to "pause" an application while it's launching. Don't quit it, but don't let it launch completely either. Just keep the icon bouncing in the dock (i.e. "freeze" the launch) for some arbitrary time. After that time, if I decide I want to quit the app after all, I can do `NSRunningApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "xyz").terminate() or .forceTerminate()`, and I can confirm with `.isTerminated()`. Otherwise, I can just "unfreeze" the app and let it finish launching.
2. What's the least power-hungry way of checking constantly for an app launch? I could just schedule a Timer to check every half-second or so, but I believe that hogs a fair amount of memory. Can I set a listener or notification to check for a 3rd-party app launch? (i.e. to run a function every time the Notes app changes isTerminated state).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could reveal also the purpose of your question. Basically you can't *"pause" an application while it's launching*.

Comment: @vadian I'm trying to figure out how an app called Cisdem AppCrypt does it. They have a trial version – if you'd like, you can download it and check it out here: https://www.cisdem.com/appcrypt-mac.html. Essentially, they've found a way to present a password dialog **while** keeping the dock icon of the locked app bouncing in the dock. So it never launches until the user passes the prompt, but when the correct password is entered, all it has to do is finish launching.

Comment: I'm doing this in a Swift playground right now – what I have so far just has a global timer going every 0.05 seconds that checks if any protected apps are running. If they are, it quits them by .terminate(), then .forceTerminate() a second later if the app is still active (.isTerminated()), then deals with user interaction. If prompt fails, it does nothing. If it succeeds, it manually launches that app again (with the instruction not to quit automatically).

Comment: I know that seems like a pretty inefficient way to do it, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do all of the checking passively (listeners, notifications, etc.) and how to keep the app in "standby" while dealing with the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably target another process and control it from Swift (or any other User-mode program), as you really need to do that in the kernel, with a kernel extension (Kext).

Apple's official framework for this is the [Kernel Authorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2127/_index.html) framework (KAuth). Using the `File Operation Scope` (described in the documentation), a kernel extension will be notified of various operations, including a program's execution and can allow or deny its access.

A working example of its usage can be seen in the open source code of [Google Santa](https://github.com/google/santa), which they use to manage their own employees' computers. As its documentation states:

> It consists of a kernel extension that monitors for executions, a userland daemon that makes execution decisions based on the contents of a SQLite database, a GUI agent that notifies the user in case of a block decision and a command-line utility for managing the system and synchronizing the database with a server.

Comment: Alright, I just looked into the KAuth docs; from what I can tell, it's probably needlessly complicated for my purposes. If the only other option is a repeating timer (or similar poll-style listener), is it possible to make it less of a power drain outside of decreasing the timeInterval?